# Avoid Celery retries for unregistered task

Tags: python, django, celery, django-celery, kombu

We have a Django app with celery to handle an asynchronous tasks. We use AWS SQS as the task broker.

We ended up with a bad task to be processed (removed the task implementation without removing the celery-beat entry). This resulted in errors:

```
Received unregistered task of type KeyError('some_deleted_task').
The message has been ignored and discarded.
```

Once we cleaned up the celery-beat entries, we continued getting errors ~2min (visibility timeout on SQS was set to 2 minutes).

Behaviour seemed to be:

1. Task added to queue, in SQS as 'Available'
2. Worker picks up the task, moves the SQS message to 'in flight'
3. Worker fails immediately due to missing implementation.
4. two minutes later, SQS moves the message from 'in flight', back to 'available'
5. Goto 2

To clear the errors, we purged the SQS queue, but this could have resulted in losing other tasks.

I'd like to configure celery so it won't keep trying these missing tasks indefinitely.

Comment: I know I can add an "empty" task with the same name to drain these bad tasks from the queue, but it would be preferable to just log a handful of errors and abort.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by the preferable behavior -- that actually sounds exactly what is happening. Celery is not _retrying_ the task, it's logging the issue, then ignoring it. SQS is simply making the message visible again. You wouldn't want to have the receipt of an unregistered task cause the message to be removed from the queue because that could result in loss of messages (for example, during rolling app deployments where two app versions could exist simultaneously). You might consider a policy to move these messages to a DLQ.

Comment: Celery may not be explictly retrying the task, but celery attempts to execute the same task repeatedly. Celery not doing anything with the message is the problem - if it failed, it should do _something_ with it (consume and queue another for retry with some backoff, move to DLQ, etc.) but I haven't found a way to configure that.

Comment: To the extent that celery lets you configure task behavior, tasks must be registered. It would be improper to handle messages it has no knowledge of how to handle. If you want someone else to happen with these unregistered tasks, it will have to be some process you setup outside of celery, like a message retention configuration in SQS. Otherwise, register the task and configure the retry/requeue behavior. I think that's the only options you have within the celery framework-provided configurations.

Answer (score 1):

Celery is not doing anything to actively *retry* the task. As the message states, the task is ignored. The task has been queued and, reasonably, celery won't remove it from the queue unless it actually executes a task associated with the message. The behavior you observe is correct and desirable.

You wouldn't want to have the receipt of an unregistered task cause the message to be removed from the queue because that could result in loss of messages. For example, if you deploy a new version of your app with a new task, but an old worker is still active (which happens with virtually all zero-downtime deployments) the old version can pick up messages from the new version and it will believe it has picked up an unregistered task. If you celery were to remove messages when it encountered unregistered tasks, this could result in loss of these messages, among other similar cases.

Some possible options within the celery framework:

**Hook into task rejection signals**

The consumer will fire the [task rejected](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#task-rejected) signal when the task is rejected. You could use this to hook into the event and do something (maybe use SQS API to move the message).

**Customize the consumer**

The celery consumer controls the behavior in this case in the [on_unknown_task](https://github.com/celery/celery/blob/117cd9ca410e8879f71bd84be27b8e69e462c56a/celery/worker/consumer/consumer.py#L513-L540) method. You could subclass and [extend the consumer](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/extending.html) to control the behavior.

Comment: I agree that we don't want to "lose" these tasks, which is why we track these errors through various tools/log processors. Our actual tasks have a retry policy, including things like backoff, jitter, max retries, etc. I'm looking to apply similar logic to these unregistered tasks. Your comment on the question mentioned moving messages to a DLQ - that's the kind of thing I would be interested in doing, but haven't been able to find a documented way to do that.

Comment: @CoatedMoose would it be acceptable to create a custom celery extension to handle unregistered tasks? You could also hook into the [task rejected](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/signals.html#task-rejected) signal.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to control the retry behaviour for these unregistered/unknown tasks. I'll prioritize maintainability of whatever options are available, but beyond that, I'm not picky about how I get there - library config, SQS config, extension, monkey patching, etc. could all be fair game.